# Hide and encrypt video files in android

Tags: android

I am working on Android Vault (e.g Files, Audio, Video, Images). I am trying to figure out a way to hide or encrypt large file like videos that won't show up in the storage directory, even you if search for them.

If anyone can help me out from this kinda problem.

I am Using Encryption and its working fine with images, but with videos it's not working as I want.

and Thanks a lot in Advance .Truly appreciated yours efforts

Comment: Your content should be on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), which is inaccessible to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To encrypt any type of file in android you can use the [EasyCrypt](https://github.com/pvasa/EasyCrypt) library.

Using `EasyCrypt` is easy, as the name suggests.

```
ECSymmetric ecSymmetric = new ECSymmetric();
ecSymmetric.encrypt(file, getString(R.string.string_resource_encryption_password), new ECResultListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgress(int i, long l, long l1) {
        // can show a progress bar here
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void onSuccess(T t) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: file encrypted");
        Log.d(TAG, "result: " + t.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NotNull String s, @NotNull Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + s);
    }
});
```

Here `file` is the Java `File` class Object for any type of file you want.

To hide the encrypted file you can just add a '.' before the name of the file.

for example:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + ".file.mp4");
```

Comment: @Warman you are welcome. please mark the question as answered.